# using the scalatest runner from an scala application

Tags: scala, continuous-integration, scalatest

I am trying to create an scala application that would kick off all the scalatests written in a package using the scalatest runner, but the runner can't seem to find any of the tests for some reason. My project is structured as below.

```
root Project
   projectA
      src
        folderA
          testA
          testB
          testC
          Main
```

in Main I have the following code

```
import org.scalatest.tools.Runner

object Main {
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
val testResult = Runner.run(Array("-o","-e", "-m", "src.folderA"))
if (!testResult) {
  System.exit(1) // exit with an error code if a test failed
}
}
}
```

When main is ran, no tests are run. I have tried this with -R as well and doesn't work either. I feel like I'm giving the path wrong but can't figure out what the issue is.

Comment: do you have a sample project somewhere on github?

Comment: can't really share the project online, but does the path for the runner depend on the path of the current running directory?